# get keyboardfilter WMI parameters in c#

Tags: c#, windows-10, wmi, windowsiot

On Windows IoT (but also on the normal Windows 10), you can enable keyboard filter and shell launcher.
I enabled UWF, KB-Filter and Shell Launcher.

Now, I can't get the parameters of my keyboardfilter with a simple C#.NET program.

```cpp
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "WEKF_Settings", null))
{
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
    }
}
```

The `UWF_Filter` is working. [WEKF_Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/wekf-settings) and [WESL_UserSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/wesl-usersetting) are not working, even if they are enabled on the OS.

I get always the exception **Provider Load Failure**, even if the application is started as administrator.

In powershell, I get the class without any problem:

```bsh
Get-CimClass wekf_settings \\.\root\standardcimv2\embedded | select -expand cimclassqualifiers
```

So the question: why can't I get the instances (with `GetInstances()`) in C# but only with powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as info (if you get the same error):
The query fails also on Powershell, if this is 32-bit.

You need to compile the program as **64bit**. Then the code will be able to query the keyboard filter.

This was the solution.